# access denied for mysql user with two hostnames in error message

Tags: mysql

A strange warning I saw in error logs.

I cannot paste the actual warning because of security reasons. So i am writing in format which I got.

a username is followed by two hostnames which looks strange to me.

`[Warning] Access denied for user 'username'@'hostname'@'ipaddress' (using password: YES)`

Comment: Use GRANT PRIVILEGES. Read [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)

Comment: Possibly the username contains \@hostname but should not and the client is adding the \@ipaddress part.

Comment: No username does not contain hostname, it is just a 5 letter word.

Comment: I am seeing this warning in error log when user is trying to connect through phpmyadmin